# Time Complexity OF NTM vs TM

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, time-complexity, nondeterminism

In Sipser, It is given Pg. 284

> Let t(n) be a function, where t(n) ≥ n. Then every t(n) time
> non-deterministic single-tape Turing machine has an equivalent 2 <sup>O(t(n))</sup>
> time deterministic single tape Turing machine

In the given proof, at end they conclude

> O(t(n)b<sup>t(n)</sup>) = 2<sup>O(t(n))</sup>.
>
> where b is the maximum number of legal choices given by N’stransition function

I am unable to understand how did they conclude so>

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Be aware of what "$2^{O(\dots)}$" means -- it's horrible abuse of notation.

Answer (score 2):

You can write, if $b\gt 1$, 
$$b^{t(n)}=2^{\log_2{b}\times t(n)}=2^{O(t(n))}$$

So,
$$O(t(n)b^{t(n)})=O(t(n)2^{O(t(n))})=O(2^{\log_2{t(n)}}2^{O(t(n))})=2^{O(t(n))}$$

To elaborate, 
$$O(x2^{O(x)})=O(2^{\log x}2^{O(x)})=O(2^{O(x)+\log x})=O(2^{O(x)})$$ which means it is eventually upper bounded by some $$c2^{O(x)}=2^{\log cO(x)}=2^{O(x)}$$

Note that if $b=1$, then the non deterministic Turing machine is effectively a deterministic Turing machine, so you can still write it as $O(t(n))$, which is as expected.

Comment: You wrote,
O(t(n) 2^x) = 2^x, in short in last step. 
But how does it prove that the deterministic turing machine can't take more than 2^x steps..??

Comment: @user2984602 $O(x2^{O(x)})=O(2^{\log x}2^{O(x)})=O(2^{O(x)+\log x})=O(2^{O(x)})$, which means it is eventually upper bounded by some $c2^{O(x)}=2^{\log cO(x)}=2^{O(x)}$. Does this clarify your question?